# Go, FreeBSD, iovec and syscalls

Tags: go, freebsd

I've been trying to make a syscall to FreeBSD's jail_set without success.

It uses an array of iovec when receiving the syscall, but returns me always a "Bad Address".

Here's the part of the code that creates the IOVEC:

```
func (p Params) buildIovec() ([]unix.Iovec, error) {
    iovSize := len(p) * 2
    iovec := make([]unix.Iovec, iovSize)
    var itr int
    for paramKey, paramValue := range p {
        arrayParamKey := []byte(paramKey)
        // Adds a nullbyte
        // Jail parameters are passed as an array   
        // of name-value pairs in the array iov, containing niov
        // elements.    Parameter names are a null-terminated
        // string, and values may be strings, integers, 
        // or other arbitrary data.
        // Ref: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=jail&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD+11.1-stable
        arrayParamKey = append(arrayParamKey, 0)
        size := len(arrayParamKey)

        iovec[itr] = unix.Iovec{
            Base: (*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&arrayParamKey)),
            Len:  uint64(size),
        }
        itr++

        rv := reflect.ValueOf(paramValue)
        var arrayValueBytes []byte
        switch rv.Kind() {
        case reflect.String:
            arrayValueBytes = []byte(rv.String())
            arrayValueBytes = append(arrayValueBytes, 0)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
        default:
            return nil, errors.New("invalid value passed in for key: " + paramKey)
        }

        arrayValueSize := len(arrayValueBytes)
        iovec[itr] = unix.Iovec{
            Base: (*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&arrayValueBytes)),
            Len: uint64(arrayValueSize),
        }
        itr++
    }
    return iovec, nil
}
```

And then the syscall is called with:

```
    _, _, e1 := unix.Syscall(uintptr(call), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&iov)), uintptr(len(iov)), flags)
```

Where call represents the jail_set int [507](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/b5a8a00c4307f6a1024e85e779c8e418ee087127/sys/kern/syscalls.c#L516), and flags is the uintptr of 1 (represents the CREATE).

Also, Params is a map[string]interface{} where the key is the key of the jail config, and the value is the value of the config (this explains the loop in the buildIovec).

This is based in  https://github.com/briandowns/jail but I've been changing some things to see if it works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your value is passing the address of the slice header for the slice of bytes, not the address of the start of the actual bytes.

`[]byte(rv.String())` will create a small slice header.

`unsafe.Pointer(C.CString(rv.String()))` will probably get you closer to working code.